# IE 10 blocked AngularJS & Jquery content to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, security, internet-explorer

I have added new AuthInterceptor to an application and it is being blocked by IE-10.

The code is loaded in iframe and when parent URL domain is different than UI and domain URL, it is not working

e.g parent browser URL: http://test1.com
iframe loading content URL: https://test2.com

It is working well in Chrome, Firefox.

It is also working well in IE 10 if IE **Privacy setting** set to Low or Accept All Cookies (To set Privacy setting go to `Internet Options > Privacy tab > Settings High Medium Low bar`)

Is it due to domain issue or HTTP or https communication issue?
How can it be fixed?

```
angular.module('app').service('AuthInterceptor', ['$location', 'appConstant', '$q', '$rootScope', '$log', function ($location,appConstant, $q, $rootScope, $log) {
    'use strict';

    var path = $location.absUrl();

    return {
        request: function (config) {


            var documentReferrer = document.referrer;
            //UI cannot be open standalone.
            if (documentReferrer === undefined || documentReferrer === ''
                //|| documentReferrer === document.location.origin
                || !(documentReferrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('x.com') > -1
                || documentReferrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('y.com') > -1
                || documentReferrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('z.com') > -1
                || documentReferrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('a.com') > -1
                || documentReferrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('b.com') > -1)) {
                RedirectToAccessDenied();
            }

            //should not allowed access without user Id.
            var UserId = path.split("?")[1].split("=")[2].split("&")[0];
            if (UserId === undefined || UserId === '' || UserId === '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') {
                RedirectToAccessDenied();
            }

            //Gateway call from UI will be authorized by access token 
             var access_token = path.split("?")[1].split("&token=")[1].split('#')[0];
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'bearer '+ token;
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                RedirectToAccessDenied();
            }
        }

    };

    function RedirectToAccessDenied() {
        $location.url('/accessDenied');
    }
}]);
```

This file is not even loaded in IE 10 with a privacy setting Medium.
Why is it getting blocked by IE what is the reason?

Comment: `Why it is getting blocked by IE what is the reason?`. **Because you have changed your browser privacy settings** :( :(

Comment: Browser setting by default at medium ...so by default it is not loading...if you change privacy setting to low then it is working that I don't want to do and can't ask client to do so...